# Dynamically set a TextView based ViewFlipper

Tags: java, android, viewflipper

I've found many answers for populating ImageView ViewFlipper from an array, but not so much help with TextView flippers populated via String[] array.  I've tried to model the other suggestions, but what I have isn't quite working.  The result right now if the first string in my array displays within the flipper view, but no flipping action occurs, and of course then, no other Strings ever show.

My XML

```
        <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/vf_tagFlipperFWR"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
```

My Code - I get my array from a helper class (FYI getTagArray works elsewhere)

```
vf_tagFlip = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.vf_tagFlipperFWR);
String[] tagArrayTemp = numberPickerHelper.getTagArray(this);
for(int i=0; i<tagArrayTemp.length; i++){
        setFlipperText(tagArrayTemp[i]);
    }
```

setFlipperText method

```
private void setFlipperText(String s) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tv.setText(s);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    tv.setTextSize(20);
    tv.setGravity(1);
    vf_tagFlip.addView(tv);
}
```